# Certain functions are undefined when called form mu-plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, mu-plugins

I have a correctly formatted php functions file in my mu-plugins/ directory.
When trying to use wp_is_mobile() or current_user_can(), I get an undefined function error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_is_mobile() in /var/www/dev.example.com/public/wp-content/mu-plugins/multisite-functions.php on line 147
```

Are certain core functions defined after the mu-plugins?
How do I fix or avoid this?
Can I simply not use certain functions in mu plugins?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling `wp_is_mobile()`, `current_user_can()`, etc? In a filter?

Comment: I was foolishly doing it outside of the filter, it is now fixed and working though.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to diggy from StackOverflow I've foudn that in the WordPress cycle, the file vars.php (containing my needed functions) is included after muplugins_loaded executes.

Including wp_is_mobile() and current_user_can() in wrapper functions fixed my problem.

**CORRECT**

```
function my_epic_function() {
    if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
      if(!wp_is_mobile()) {
        //code to be executed
      }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_epic_function');
```

**INCORRECT**

```
function my_epic_function() {
    //code to be executed
}
if(current_user_can( 'edit_posts' )) {
  if(!wp_is_mobile()) {
    add_action('init', 'my_epic_function');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some example code to your answer to help any future visitors?

Comment: Make sure you mark your answer Accepted so that others can benefit from your learning, too. (I think there's a 48-hour wait before you can accept your own answer.)